# Go's Type Inference Algorithm

Tags: go, type-inference

What type inference algorithm does the Go compiler use?

I tried looking this up on golang but I can't find documentation. I am tempted to assume that it would be Hindley-Milner, but I would like to know for sure

Comment: What algorithm inference algorithm do you use to assume it would be Hindley-Milner ?

Answer (score 23):

Go certainly doesn't use Hindley-Milner. Why would you think that? In fact, **Go doesn't have type inference in general**, only with the `:=` construct, and that uses the extremely simple rule of taking the evaluated type of the right-hand side and applying it to the newly-declared variable on the left. It's actually pretty darn similar to C++11's `auto` keyword (except without the rules on handling `const` and references).

Comment: Worth noting: The types *"infered"* with `:=` are determined at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @Tom: Is it even possible to "infer" types at runtime?

Comment: Yes, in duck-typed languages like PHP for example.

Comment: @Tom: That's not type inference. That's just runtime type information.

Comment: That's not type inference, that's dynamic typing. Dynamic languages like PHP don't have and don't need type inference. Type inference is syntactic sugar for statically-typed languages. Both type inference and dynamic typing have nothing to do with Duck typing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: Dynamic languages are not duck-typed, they are untyped. On the other hand, structurally typed languages such as Golang, TypeScript and OCaml are duck-typed.