# How is type inference implemented in a language like C++11 or Go?

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, type-inference

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589255/gos-type-inference-algorithm) question here, but it doesn't answer what I had in mind in particular detail.
If languages like Go or C++11 don't use an inference algorithm like Damas-Milner, what exactly do they do? I don't think it's as simple as taking the type on the right hand side because what if you had something like:

```
5 + 3.4
```

How would the compiler decipher what type that is? Is there any algorithm that isn't as simple as

```
if left is integer and right is float:
    return float;
if left is float and right is integer:
    return float;
etc... for every possible pattern
```

And if you could explain things in simple terms that would be great. I'm not studying compiler construction or any of the theoretical topics in great detail, and I don't really speak functional languages or complex mathematical notation.

Comment: It's more like: *"if left is integer and right is float, convert left to float, and add the two floats"*. Conversions are done (as necessary) for each binary operator in the expression, and the result ends up being the highest ranking type in the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't think it's as simple as taking the type on the right hand side

For basic type inference of the form `auto var = some_expression;`, it is exactly that simple. Every well-typed expression has exactly one type and that type will be the type of `var`. There will be no implicit conversion from the type of the expression to another type (as there might be if you gave an explicit type for `var`).

> what if you had something like:
>
> ```
> 5 + 3.4
> ```

The question "What is the type of `5 + 3.4`?" isn't specific to type inference, C++ compilers always had to answer this question - even before type inference was introduced.

So let's take a step back and look at how a C++ compiler typechecks the statement `some_type var = some_expression;`:

First it determines the type of `some_expression`. So in code you can imagine something like `Type exp_type = type_of(exp);`. Now it checks whether `exp_type` is equal to `some_type` or there exists an implicit conversion from `exp_type` to `some_type`. If so, the statement is well-typed and `var` is introduced into the environment as having the type `some_type`. Otherwise it is not.

Now when we introduce type inference and write `auto var = some_expression;`, the equation changes as such: We still do `Type exp_type = type_of(exp);`, but instead of then comparing it to another type or applying any implicit conversions, we instead simply set `exp_type` as the type of `var`.

So now let's get back to `5 + 3.4`. What is its type and how does the compiler determine it? In C++ its type is `double`. The exact rules to determine the type of an arithmetic expression are listed in the C++ standard (look for "usual arithmetic conversions"), but basically boil down to this: Of the two operand types, pick the one that can represent the greater range of values. If the type is smaller than `int`, convert both operands to `int`. Otherwise convert both operands to the type you picked.

In code you'd implement this by assigning each numeric type a conversion rank and then doing something like this:

```
Type type_of_binary_arithmetic_expression(Type lhs_type, Type rhs_type) {
    int lhs_rank = conversion_rank(lhs_type);
    int rhs_rank = conversion_rank(rhs_type);
    if(lhs_rank < INT_RANK && rhs_rank < INT_RANK) return INT_TYPE;
    else if(lhs_rank < rhs_rank) return rhs_type;
    else return lhs_type;
}
```

Presumably the rules for Go are somewhat different, but the same principles apply.